# Are there any decent PHP forums where I can submit program designs and code for critique?

Tags: php, resources

I don't feel that stackoverflow is the best website for getting critiqued on my code, as it caters to single answers. I have always read and practiced alone (aside from some forums) as I did not go to school for programming or computer science, and thus do not have any peers that I can go to for advice, critique, or direction.

Are there websites where I can submit my code and program designs (UML diagrams) for critique and advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can post UML diagrams using some devoted (image hosting) service to save forums bandwidth. The same with long code, www.pastebin.com and similar (or even Github) are perfect for that.

Then, one decent forum I know is: http://forums.devnetwork.net/
There is special Coding Critique section there.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite a forum, but [Refactor My Code's PHP section](http://refactormycode.com/codes/recent/php) is a good place to post your code and get comments and refactorings. Linking to the UML diagrams in your code's description won't hurt.